# Regular expression for PennTreeBank tags in Java

Tags: regex, nlp, regex-negation

Please consider some examples of PennTreeBank Tags:

```
ADJP -ADV ADVP -BNF CC CD -CLF -CLR -HLN PRP$ PR-P$ NP
```

Please consider an instance of my program execution.

```
Enter your regex: ^-{0,1}[A-Z]{1,6}-{0,1}[A-Z]{0,1}\${0,1}
Enter input string to search: -HLN
I found the text "-HLN" starting at index 0 and ending at index 4.
```

It works fine.

My task actually is to successfully identify any tag (please refer to tag examples above) except the "NP" tag. I wrote the regex as below.

```
Enter your regex: (^-{0,1}[A-Z]{1,6}-{0,1}[A-Z]{0,1}\${0,1})&&^(NP)
Enter input string to search: -HLN
No match found.
```

It is not the desired outcome.

Could someone help me modify the regex to suit the task?

Thank you.

Comment: What are your alternative suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The ^ as a "not" operator only works inside a character class. So `[^abcd]` means any character that's not an a, b, c, or d.

If I were you I'd use your original one and check for the special case in the code! Saves you lots of headaches; and complicated regexes are best avoided because they can get very slow.

Comment: {The ^ as a "not" operator only works inside a character class. So [^abcd] means any character that's not an a, b, c, or d.} <-- Thank you for pointing that bit out.

Comment: no problem :) looking at the other answer to your post, you can see that not everything that is easily described in an English sentence, is easily matched by a regex.

Answer (score 0):

This may be off base, but this is my take on it ...

This is hard to do even if you have lookaround assertions.
What makes it hard is the boundry conditions:
`(?:^|(?<=[^A-Z\$-]))(?!NP(?:$|[^A-Z\$-]))-?[A-Z]{1,6}-?[A-Z]?\$?(?=$|[^A-Z\$-])`

Expanded:

```
(?:^|(?<=[^A-Z\$-]))      # Behind us, this is OK: BOL or NOT A-Z, nor '$', nor '-'
(?!NP(?:$|[^A-Z\$-]))     # In front of us, exclude: 'NP' followed by NOT A-Z, nor '$', nor '-'
-?                        # This is your accepted PTB forms:
[A-Z]{1,6}                #   ..  
-?                        #   ..
[A-Z]?                    #   ..
\$?                       #   ..
(?=$|[^A-Z\$-])           # Finally, followed by EOL or NOT A-Z, nor '$', nor '-'
```

A weary Perl example follows:

```
$ptb = 'ADJP{-ADV} ADVP {-BNF NP CC} CD -CLF -CLR -HLN PRP$ PR-P$ NP';

while ($ptb =~
 /
   (?:^|(?<=[^A-Z\$-]))
   (?!NP(?:$|[^A-Z\$-]))
   -?
   [A-Z]{1,6}
   -?
   [A-Z]?
   \$?
   (?=$|[^A-Z\$-])
 /xg )

{
   print "'$&'\n";
}
```

Output:

```
'ADJP'
'-ADV'
'ADVP'
'-BNF'
'CC'
'CD'
'-CLF'
'-CLR'
'-HLN'
'PRP$'
'PR-P$'
```